# maven naming convention 32 vs 64 bit and windows vs linux

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a library that has 4 different versions: 32 and 64bit windows and 32 and 64bit linux. I'm trying to figure out what name each library when uploading them to the maven repository. For now I have:

```xml
  <!--windows 32bit -->
  <groupId>com.lib-name.win</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib-name</artifactId>
  <classifier>x86<classifier>
  <version>10</version>

  <!--windows 64bit -->
  <groupId>com.lib-name.win</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib-name</artifactId>
  <classifier>x86-64<classifier>
  <version>10</version>

  <!--linux 32bit -->
  <groupId>com.lib-name.nix</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib-name</artifactId>
  <classifier>x86<classifier>
  <version>10</version>

  <!--linux 64bit -->
  <groupId>com.lib-name.nix</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib-name</artifactId>
  <classifier>x86-64<classifier>
  <version>10</version>
```

Is there a more standard way of giving names to the jars in maven for this case? Or am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm not aware of any convention in this field. I guess, you should only care about the fact that user understands which library he's got to use :)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking it might be more appropriate to have the same groupId and artifactId for all 4 versions (since they are really the same thing) and having 4 different classifiers (x86-win, x86-64-win, x86-nix, x86-64-nix). Wanted to see if there were any shortcomings of either ways.

Comment: Well, idea with one and only `groupId` and `artifactId` is not bad either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://maven.apache.org/pom.html:

> **classifier:**
>   The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number.
>
> As a motivation for this element, consider for example a project that offers an artifact targeting JRE 1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the second one with jdk14 such that clients can choose which one to use.

The latter paragraph suggests they intended classifiers to perform the sort of task you have in mind.

However, in my experience, most projects I've encountered release separate artifacts for each vein of a project. I personally prefer that approach, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the "separate artifacts for each vein of a project?". I'm curious to see what the popular way to tackling this problem is.

Comment: The first one that springs to mind is BouncyCastle, which produces variants for different Java versions: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/

Comment: Just the example I was looking for :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think using the same group and artifact id with different classifiers is the cleanest approach. Think about how sources jars are released by the maven source plugin (its just another classifier). Take a look at this as well :

[One Artifact for different configurations](http://www.jayway.com/2010/01/21/one-artifact-with-multiple-configurations-in-maven/)